# Custom Intune OMA-URI to block USB Storage is blocking Printes via USB and NEt (netshared printers)

Tags: mdm, intune

I spend days trying to find information about why the Custom OMA-URI USB policy in Intune is blocking also printers in my net. Block USB printer is very logic but block also net shared printers is not logic for me and thats the problem.

When this policy is applied to a Device the Net Printer shows "DISCONECTED" and the Device with have Shared the PRinter via USB without the policy is working fine.

I apllied this:

**Group for RemovableMedia XML**
OMA-URI ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyGroups/%7b56779d19-346e-4219-81a0-8b6a0a35a348%7d/GroupData

```
<Group Id="{56779d19-346e-4219-81a0-8b6a0a35a348}">
<!-- ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyGroups/%7b56779d19-346e-4219-81a0-8b6a0a35a348%7d/GroupData -->
    <MatchType>MatchAny</MatchType>
    <DescriptorIdList>
        <PrimaryId>RemovableMediaDevices</PrimaryId>
    </DescriptorIdList>
</Group>
```

**USB Approved Group XML (Its working fine to allow some USB) XML**
OMA-URI ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyGroups/%7bf1d51d30-cf1e-453d-a275-152a770b1f83%7d/GroupData

```
<Group Id="{f1d51d30-cf1e-453d-a275-152a770b1f83}">
<!-- ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyGroups/%7bf1d51d30-cf1e-453d-a275-152a770b1f83%7d/GroupData -->
    <Matchtype>Matchany</Matchtype>
    <DescriptorIdlist>
<InstancePathId>USBSTOR\DISK&amp;VEN_TTULTRA&amp;PROD_SENSITECH_INC.&amp;REV_\7&amp;8D3D3A7&amp;0&amp;00000000001A&amp;0</InstancePathId>
<InstancePathId>USBSTOR\DISK&amp;VEN_ATMEL&amp;PROD_ON-CHIP_VIRTUAL&amp;REV_1.00\7&amp;D039C83&amp;0&amp;123123123123&amp;0</InstancePathId>
<InstancePathId>USBSTOR\DISK&amp;VEN_GENERIC&amp;PROD_USB_FLASH_DISK&amp;REV_0.00\__0XFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&amp;0</InstancePathId>
    </DescriptorIdlist>
</Group>
```

**
**Intune ALlow Policy XML****
OMA-URI ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyRules/%7baa5767cd-852d-45c4-8409-7adc0147dd45%7d/RuleData

```
<PolicyRule Id="{aa5767cd-852d-45c4-8409-7adc0147dd45}">
<!-- ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyRules/%7baa5767cd-852d-45c4-8409-7adc0147dd45%7d/RuleData -->
    <Name>Allow Write and Execute to Removable Storage</Name>
    <IncludedIdList>
        <GroupId>{f1d51d30-cf1e-453d-a275-152a770b1f83}</GroupId>
    </IncludedIdList>
    <ExcludedIdList>
    </ExcludedIdList>
    <Entry Id="{1f910990-dd5d-4a99-a75b-3b460b16ce57}">
        <Type>Allow</Type>
        <Options>16</Options>
        <AccessMask>63</AccessMask>
    </Entry>
</PolicyRule>
```

**Restriction Policy XML**
OMA-URI ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyRules/%7b6edabff0-b59f-40db-b1fd-d94807c0bb87%7d/RuleData

```
<PolicyRule Id="{6edabff0-b59f-40db-b1fd-d94807c0bb87}">
<!-- ./Vendor/MSFT/Defender/Configuration/DeviceControl/PolicyRules/%7b6edabff0-b59f-40db-b1fd-d94807c0bb87%7d/RuleData -->
    <Name>Block Write and Execute to Removable Storage</Name>
    <IncludedIdList>
        <GroupId>{56779d19-346e-4219-81a0-8b6a0a35a348}</GroupId>
    </IncludedIdList>
    <ExcludedIdList>
        <GroupId>{f1d51d30-cf1e-453d-a275-152a770b1f83}</GroupId>
    </ExcludedIdList>
    <Entry Id="{bab49e44-9fc9-44d0-8937-8f7c8c17a290}">
        <Type>Deny</Type>
        <Options>0</Options>
        <AccessMask>3</AccessMask>
    </Entry>
</PolicyRule>
```

The policy working fine blocking all de USB devices and allowed the USB devices that previusly I put into the "USB Approved Group XML".

I dont know if I forgot a line or config.

THank you guys a lot in advance.

THe policy have to block any USB device and also permite print over net on shared printers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the custom OMA-URI USB policy in Intune is blocking printers in the net is because the policy is blocking all the USB devices. It is not possible to differentiate between a USB storage device and a USB printer using Intune policies.

However, you can try to modify the custom OMA-URI USB policy to allow USB printers as an exception. You can add the USB printer’s vendor ID and product ID in the USB Approved Group XML. This will allow the USB printer to work even if the policy is applied.